# return render_template in flask isn't running in methods using POST and GET

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I need to send some data to my html page in the render template line. I dont think the line is even executing in the POST version of the method because I can change the html page and it doesnt change at all, but if i change it in the normal non POST version it messes stuff up.

here is the method that the line isnt running in

```
@bp.route('/livechat', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def livechat_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_id = session.get('user_id')
        db = get_db()
        if user_id is None:
            return redirect(url_for('auth.start_page'))
        else:
            user = db.execute(
                'SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?', (user_id,)
            ).fetchone()
            if user is None:
                return redirect(url_for('auth.start_page'))
            user_details = {
                'email': user['email'],
            }
            print (request.form['flag'], file=sys.stderr)
            print ('flag 0', file=sys.stderr)

            #the first ajax call for creating the conversation
            otherEmail = request.form['otherEmail']
            reversed = True
            concat_users = user_details['email'] + ":" + otherEmail
            concat_reverse = otherEmail + ":" + user_details['email']

            #check to see who started the conversation
            check_dup  = db.execute(
                'SELECT * FROM total_msg WHERE identifier = ?', (concat_reverse,)
            ).fetchone()

            if check_dup is None:
                reversed = False
                db.execute(
                    'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO total_msg (identifier, total_messages) VALUES (?, ?)', (concat_users, 0,)
                )
                db.commit()
            # the second ajax call for entering a message into the database
            if request.form['flag'] == '1':
                #adds 1 to the conversation message count and enters the message
                print ('flag 1', file=sys.stderr)
                if not reversed:
                    hack = db.execute('SELECT * FROM total_msg WHERE identifier = ?', (concat_users,)).fetchone()

                    db.execute(
                        'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO total_msg (identifier, total_messages) VALUES (?, ?)', (concat_users, hack['total_messages'] +1,)
                    )
                    db.commit()

#                    concat_users_msgnumber = concat_users + ":" + str(hack['total_messages'])
                    db.execute(
                        'INSERT INTO messages (id, identifier_msg_nmbr, message, sender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', (hack['total_messages'], concat_users, request.form['the_message'], user_details['email'],)
                    )
                    db.commit()
                else:
                    hack2 = db.execute('SELECT * FROM total_msg WHERE identifier = ?', (concat_reverse,)).fetchone()

                    db.execute(
                        'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO total_msg (identifier, total_messages) VALUES (?, ?)', (concat_reverse, hack2['total_messages'] +1,)
                    )
                    db.commit()

#                    concat_reverse_msgnumber = concat_reverse + ":" + str(hack2['total_messages'])
                    db.execute(
                        'INSERT INTO messages (id, identifier_msg_nmbr, message, sender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', (hack2['total_messages'], concat_reverse, request.form['the_message'], user_details['email'],)
                    )
                    db.commit()

            if not reversed:
                print ('if', file=sys.stderr)
                chat_history = db.execute(
                    'SELECT * FROM messages WHERE identifier_msg_nmbr = ?', (concat_users,)
                ).fetchall()
#                print (chat_history, file=sys.stderr)
            else:
                print ('else', file=sys.stderr)
                chat_history = db.execute(
                    'SELECT * FROM messages WHERE identifier_msg_nmbr = ?', (concat_reverse,)
                ).fetchall()
            print (chat_history, file=sys.stderr)

            return render_template('main/livechat.html', user=user_details, chat_history=chat_history)
```

and here is how im using the data in the html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col s4">
<h6 class="bold">messages</h6>
</div>
</div>
{% for item in chat_history %}
<div class="row">
<div class="col s4">
<p>{{item.message}}</p>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your flask route, all your code is inside if block of POST. When page loads first time, method is GET. There is no routine to handle this case.

In your html template, there is no form. So I guess there is no way to submit data using POST. Therefor routine never encounters POST method.

This is all based on the code snippet you have shared.

The way I will do it is as follows --

```
@bp.route('/livechat', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def livechat_post():
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        #various logic, code here for the cases when method is POST
        return redirect(url_for('somepage'))

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        #codes for the situations when method is GET
        #also pass form if form is submitted for the POST method in render_template
    #other logics
    return render_template('main/livechat.html', user=user_details, chat_history=chat_history)
```